# Unity Ridgidbody Constraints, Freeze Position Y

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to freeze the y position of a block in **Unity**.
Here is my **C#** code:

```
var test = GetComponent<Rigidbody>().constraints;
test = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionY;
```

It comes up with **no errors** however the Y position doesn't freeze.

Could someone help me? I have read the documentation but it just says to do what I have done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RigidbodyConstaints` is an **enumeration** (`enum`, mind that small word [in the doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RigidbodyConstraints.html)), you must change it directly without making a copy of it first. With that code, you're pulling a copy of that enum, then modify it, that's why it *this* fails:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PosFreezer : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start () {
        var rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        var constr = rb.constraints; //grab a copy (NOT a reference)
        constr = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionY; //(modify the copy)
    }
}
```

This does not:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PosFreezer : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start () {
        var rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        //Modify the constraints directly.
        rb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionY;
    }
}
```

So, remember, every `enum` is a **value type**, like a `struct`, in comparison to an instance of a `class`, which is a `reference type`. Grabbing a copy of a value type and modifying it localy probably doesn't do what you want. Your code would however also have worked if you had written:

```
var test = GetComponent<Rigidbody>().constraints;
test = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionY;
GetComponent<Rigidbody>().constraints = test;
```

But that's to messy and unreadable anyways.